# Is there a Kotlin or Java lib for listening for audio commands? (Want to trigger a Halloween display when kids yell 'TRICK OR TREAT')

Tags: java, audio, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Goal:

1. On a low-end device (raspberry pi 3)
2. Listen for a fixed set of audio phrase commands (my version of 'Hey Google' or 'Hey Siri')
3. That can be a very constrained vocabulary (less than 10 commands)
4. Trigger a Kotlin function when the command is detected.
5. Without using a ton of CPU, or a ton of network bandwidth.

AFAIK modern edge devices (Echo, Smart Phones, Google Home, etc) have very fancy hardware+software solutions that allow them to continuously listen for keywords without sucking up a ton of CPU, and without having to send all audio up to a cloud server.  I'd like to have the same, but am not sure if it is even possible - I'm sure they trained their minimal and efficient 'Hey Siri' ML model to handle all sorts of accents, volumes, cadence, ages, background noise, etc.

- The Java Speech API (JSAPI) seems... iffy.  Many of the examples are old, and either point to unsupported libs, or ended up using Google Cloud Speech.
- This doesn't **have** to be a Java/Kotlin library, I could also wrap a native command listener process.
- I'm looking at ML Kit and Firebase ML, but didn't see audio to command conversion.
- It would be best if I could tune the sensitivity, small children wearing costume masks yell 'TWIC R TREET' or 'TMURMP... TWEEF' or whatever should still do it.
- ... But not a pure volume detector, a car driving by shouldn't trigger it.

Any suggestions?  Or is this unreasonable to ask of an rpi?

Comment: You'd better have it in Python, not java. Java on RPi is meh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a library like [CMU Sphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/) which works offline, not requiring other online servers.
Sometimes the recognized results are quite inaccurate. To solve that problem I used a much smaller dictionary than the default provided one. I never fully tested it on a Raspberry Pi but I think it should work.

Comment: That looks great!  I got step 1 working.  Any suggestions on Keywords?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855329/cmusphinx-simplest-keyword-wake-word-example

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a quite useful library that I recommend: https://cmusphinx.github.io/

Comment: That looks great!  I got step 1 working.  Any suggestions on Keywords?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855329/cmusphinx-simplest-keyword-wake-word-example